# How to copy a list of files from one directory to another and modify the destination file name on the fly

Tags: linux, shell-script, cp

Could you propose a way to copy a list of files from one directory to another.

During copying the script should capitalize the first letter of the filename and lowercase all other letters.

Comment: Are you asking for help, or are you asking me to write it **for** you?

Comment: Maybe you should show us some code that proves you tried to solve it and couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

For your consideration:

```
for i in *;
do
    fletter=`echo $i| cut -b 1`;                 # FIRST LETTER
    rest=`echo $i | cut -b 2-`;                  # THE REST
    fletter=`echo $fletter | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]"`;# CAPITILIZE FIRST LETTER
    rest=`echo $rest | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]"`;      # LOWER CASE THE REST
    cp "$i" "/target/directory/$fletter$rest" ;  # COPY TO DESTINATION
done
```

Here, `*` will expand to the files in the current directory. If you want this to be restricted to *files* only, consider the following:

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do
    # rest of the script
done
```

Comment: Why `for i in $(ls)` and not `for i in *`?

Comment: @slhck I used this form to allow him to figure it out how to extend the example into more appropriate : `\ls -p | grep -v "/"` to process only files - not directories.

Comment: That's a really bad way to process only files and not directories and I would recommend against it, for multiple reasons. See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 — in your example you should also quote the variables in order to be able to handle files with spaces or globbing characters in their name.